# How can I copy geometry table from spatialite?

Tags: sqlite, qgis, spatialite

I tried spatialite:

```
create table Twn_free_way as select * from Twn_road;
```

This works fine but I can not copy the complete table.

[image]

Comment: I cannot read your mind. Some more details will help me help you.

Comment: I found SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('Twn_free_way','GEOMETRY',4326,'POINT','XY')  , AND in Qgis If You want trun CSV to sqlite ,You must to   appropriate SRID in output menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geometry column must be described in the `geometry_columns` [metadata table](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/metadata.html).

To add this entry, use the [AddGeometryColumn function](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/spatialite-sql-2.3.0.html):

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('tablename', 'MyGeoColumn', 1234, 'POINT');
```

Comment: but I use  Create table Twn_free_way as select， How can I update the colunm type to geomrtry，You can see my image thanks!!

Comment: Then use the appropriate values for the table/column names and SRID.

Comment: I had to use SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn(...), as mentioned bt user3513254